# count occurences of successive characters of a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a `String` and I need to count occurances of successive characters of the string.

```
String s1="aabbcccaaa";
```

It should print output as

```
a2b2c3a3
```

String s1="aabbcccaaa";

```
char c[]=s1.toCharArray();
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer> map=new LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer>();




for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
{
    Character c1=c[i];
    Integer frequency=map.get(c1);
    map.put(c1, (frequency==null)?1:frequency+1);

    if(map.size()>1 && c[i]!=c[i-1])
    {
        sb.append(c[i-1]+""+map.get(c[i-1]));
        map.remove(c[i-1]);
    }



}
sb.append(map);
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Ok, please go ahead and count :)

Comment: and why exactly should we write whole code for you?
at least try it out first

Comment: thanks.. I have tried to iterate the elements and used map to put key as an element and value as its occurance. I am not sure how i can achieve counts if same elements occur again..

Comment: show the code you've done so far, ask specific question where you're stuck and we'll pick it up from there. in general, learn how to use this good site in a constructive manner

Comment: You can do it....keep trying

Comment: Still waiting for ready sollution without trying Yourself ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749176/counting-the-number-of-occurences-of-characters-in-a-string

Comment: I tried something like this..

Comment: Can you check the code and help me how effectively i can do it

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how i can achieve counts if same elements occur again.

Hint #1: Test the current character against the previous one.

Hint #2: Ask yourself, why do you need to use a `Map`?